# How to translate java generics into Delphi

Tags: java, delphi, generics, delphi-xe2

I'm translating Nat Pryce's `Maybe` class into Delphi.
Here's some background: http://www.natpryce.com/articles/000776.html

Most of it is easy, but...
**How would I translate this declaration from Java into Delphi?**

```
public abstract <U> Maybe<U> to(Function<? super T, ? extends U> mapping);
```

It's an abstract virtual function `&to` that takes a `function` named `mapping` as parameter, but I'm not sure how to model this.

For context, here's the full code:

```
package com.natpryce.maybe;

import com.google.common.base.Function;
import com.google.common.base.Predicate;

import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Iterator;

public abstract class Maybe<T> implements Iterable<T> {
    public abstract boolean isKnown();
    public abstract T otherwise(T defaultValue);
    public abstract Maybe<T> otherwise(Maybe<T> maybeDefaultValue);
    public abstract <U> Maybe<U> to(Function<? super T, ? extends U> mapping);
    public abstract Maybe<Boolean> query(Predicate<? super T> mapping);

    public static <T> Maybe<T> unknown() {
        return new Maybe<T>() {
            @Override
            public boolean isKnown() {
                return false;
            }

            public Iterator<T> iterator() {
                return Collections.<T>emptyList().iterator();
            }

            @Override
            public T otherwise(T defaultValue) {
                return defaultValue;
            }

            @Override
            public Maybe<T> otherwise(Maybe<T> maybeDefaultValue) {
                return maybeDefaultValue;
            }

            @Override
            public <U> Maybe<U> to(Function<? super T, ? extends U> mapping) {
                return unknown();
            }

            @Override
            public Maybe<Boolean> query(Predicate<? super T> mapping) {
                return unknown();
            }

            @Override
            public String toString() {
                return "unknown";
            }

            @Override
            @SuppressWarnings({"EqualsWhichDoesntCheckParameterClass"})
            public boolean equals(Object obj) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public int hashCode() {
                return 0;
            }
        };
    }

    public static <T> Maybe<T> definitely(final T theValue) {
        return new DefiniteValue<T>(theValue);
    }

    private static class DefiniteValue<T> extends Maybe<T> {
        private final T theValue;

        public DefiniteValue(T theValue) {
            this.theValue = theValue;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isKnown() {
            return true;
        }

        public Iterator<T> iterator() {
            return Collections.singleton(theValue).iterator();
        }

        @Override
        public T otherwise(T defaultValue) {
            return theValue;
        }

        @Override
        public Maybe<T> otherwise(Maybe<T> maybeDefaultValue) {
            return this;
        }

        @Override
        public <U> Maybe<U> to(Function<? super T, ? extends U> mapping) {
            return definitely(mapping.apply(theValue));
        }

        @Override
        public Maybe<Boolean> query(Predicate<? super T> mapping) {
            return definitely(mapping.apply(theValue));
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "definitely " + theValue.toString();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object o) {
            if (this == o) return true;
            if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

            DefiniteValue<?> that = (DefiniteValue<?>) o;

            return theValue.equals(that.theValue);

        }

        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            return theValue.hashCode();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can use this class as an Oasis album title generator

Comment: You might take a look at [Spring.Nullable<T>](http://www.spring4d.org/spring4d-in-action/nullable-types/).

Comment: As a side not, let me say that the real problem that the above code avoids is somewhat unique to Java, and that the idiom in Delphi is to check `if Assigned(X)` before calling X.Something on anything that might be null.  I think java's disgusting Exception model and semantics (ever seen a block of 30 checked-exception catches in a row, for example, in Java codebases?) are part of the reason for the above code and type and blog post.

Comment: @WarrenP, I know, I wanted some exercise on how to get round Delphi's lack of covarianace etc. Even though they look simular the `feel` of generics in java, C# and Delphi is quite different. Java's generics feel great, but then there's _type erasure_ **sigh**.

Comment: Essentially, most problems in C# and Java that involve covariance are best solved another way in Delphi, usually without needing Generics at all. IN other words, go back to square 1 and write your own hand rolled solution, sans Generics.

Comment: @WarrenP, thanks, but the whole point of the exercise was to use generics... I just wanted to get a grip on the differences between Java and Delphi here.

Comment: I think you've got the gist now. It's good for containers, and not much else.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Java code takes advantage of covariance and contravariance in parameter types. The argument to `to` should be a function with one parameter. The parameter's type can be `T` *or any supertype of `T`*. The function should return a value of type `U` *or any subtype of `U`*.

The `to` function is going to call `mapping` and pass it the value of type `T` that it currently holds (if it holds any value at all), so the parameter type of `mapping` needs to be something that a `T` could be assigned to. That includes `T`, `Object`, and whatever other types lie between them in the hierarchy.

Similarly, `to` is going to use the result of `mapping` to get a value of type `U`. `Mapping` doesn't have to be declared to return `U` specifically, but whatever type it returns needs to be assignable to `U`.

There's no way to express those constraints in Delphi. The best you can do is request a function type that uses literally `T` and `U`:

```delphi
function &to<U>(mapping: TFunc<T, U>): Maybe<U>;
```

You *might* be able to express the constraint on `U` by introducing another type parameter:

```delphi
function &to<U: class; V: U>(mapping: TFunc<T, V>): Maybe<U>;
```

I don't know whether type parameters can be used as constraints for other parameters in the same argument list, though. I'm also not sure the compiler could infer the value of `V` in that context, so calling `to` would be cumbersome.

On the other hand, if virtual methods can't have new generic parameters (like `U`), then the constraints don't matter at all because you can't declare the method to begin with.

However, according to the reference implementation, there are only two concrete implementations of `Maybe`, so  one possibility could be to implement `to` as a *non-virtual* function and then just check the run-time type manually. It wouldn't be pretty. Something like this:

```delphi
if Self is TUnknown<T> then
  Result := unknown<U>
else
  Result := definitely(mapping(TDefiniteValue<T>(Self).value));
```

Comment: Please keep in mind that I don't have Delphi, certainly not a version that supports generics, so if my idea is sound, but the syntax off, please fix the syntax.

Comment: How can you have a gold badge in the `delphi` tag if you don't have Delphi?

Comment: @Johan He did have Delphi once upon a time, but why do you need a compiler to answer questions?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, I get that, I also get that that sort of discussion is off-topic; curiosity get the better of me I guess.

Comment: @Johan Big up for Rob though. He's a C++ guru by day, but still remembers Delphi. I think he's the best regular Delphi answerer here on the Stack, FWIW. His answers are always beautifully written and invariably full of insight. And he hardly ever makes mistakes, unlike somebody else I can think of.....  ;-)

Comment: I got a gold badge because I answered a bunch of Delphi questions before David joined.

Answer (score 2):

Well, let's ignore the constraints to begin with. The Java type [`Function<T,R>`](http://download.java.net/jdk8/docs/api/java/util/function/Function.html) maps onto [`TFunc<T,R>`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.SysUtils.TFunc) in Delphi. Beyond that the function `to` is generic on type `U`, but a method of `Maybe<T>`. So that leads us to:

```
type
  Maybe<T> = class
    function &to<U>(mapping: TFunc<T, U>): Maybe<U>; virtual; abstract;
  end;
```

Unfortunately that does not compile. The compiler emits *E2533 Virtual, dynamic and message methods cannot have type parameters* which is a new one for me. That's something of a disappointment.

**Update:** As Rob points out, and I had not got round to thinking about the constraints by the time his answer appeared, neither of those constraints can be expressed in Delphi.

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if covariant/contravariant/type-constraint-Object-Pascal became a Possibility in some future LLVM-Delphi compiler, but for now, we're miles from that.